# Simultaneous exponential equations

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, exponential-function, physics

I don't know exactly where exactly the equation applies. I don't think it is that important for solving the problem. It's about the following equation:

$$
E(t) = E_0 (1- e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}})
$$

We are looking for $\tau$ and $E_0$ under the condition that we have given two points $A$ and $B$ on the graph.

Is there a unique analytic solution to the above problem? No approximate solution should be determined using methods such as regression or Lagrange interpolation.

My approach:

Given the two points $A(x_1|y_1)$ and $B(x_2|y_2)$, we obtain the following system

\begin{align*}
E_0 (1- e^{-\frac{x_1}{\tau}}) &= y_1 \\
E_0 (1- e^{-\frac{x_2}{\tau}}) &= y_2
\end{align*}

From here I don't know exactly how to solve the system of equations. Is there a solution at all? If a solution exists, under what conditions is the solution unique?

Comment: If you divide the two equations to eliminate $E_0$, you are left with an equation of the form $g(z) = a e^{p z} + b e^{q z} + c = 0$ which unknown is $z=1/\tau$. It is easy to prove that $g$ is either monotonic or has at most one change in monotonicity. This tells you that there are at most two solutions except in exceptional cases such as $y_1=y_2=0$.

Comment: If you have informations about the signs of $\tau, x_i, y_i$, it could help you tell if there is 0, 1 or 2 solutions.

Comment: @Gribouillis Is there perhaps a formal proof when the solution is unique?

Answer (score 4):

*This is a typical exponential decay problem which will be treated as such (that is to say assuming that $(x_1,y_1,c_2,y_2)$ are all positive*

To make the problem better conditioned, let $\tau=\frac 1k$

\begin{align*}
E_0 (1- e^{-k x_1}) &= y_1 \\
E_0 (1- e^{-k x_2}) &= y_2
\end{align*}

Making the ratio
$$\frac {y_2}{y_1}=\frac{1- e^{-k x_2} } {1- e^{-k x_1} }$$ which will require a numerical method. To make the solver more happy, rewrite the above and consider that you look for the zero of function
$$F(k)=\log \left(y_2+y_1 \,e^{-k x_2}\right)-\log \left(y_1+y_2\, e^{-k x_1}\right)$$

For an example, using $A(100|45)$ and  $B(150|60)$. Since $F(0)=0$, compute a few values $F(n \Delta)$ until you have
$$F(n \Delta)<0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad F((n+1) \Delta)>0 $$ For this example, using $\Delta=0.002$ the solution is between $k=0.004$ and $k=0.006$.

Start Newton iterations at the midpoint of the range and the iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & k_n \\
 0 & 0.005000000000 \\
 1 & 0.005304125986 \\
 2 & 0.005289971732 \\
 3 & 0.005289941886 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using one of the equations, then $E_0=109.542$ and $\tau=189.038$.

**Edit** *(to be handled with care, may be)*

Suppose that $k$ is small. Perform a series expansion around $k=0$ to obtain as a *possible estimate*
$$k_0=\frac{2 (y_1+y_2) (x_1 y_2-x_2 y_1)}{\left(x_1^2-x_2^2\right) y_1   y_2}$$

For the working example, this gives
$$k_0=\frac{7}{1500}=0.00466667 \qquad \qquad\qquad \color{red}{\huge !!}$$

**Edit**

Consider now the function
$$G(k)= \left(y_2+y_1 \,e^{-k x_2}\right)-\left(y_1+y_2\, e^{-k x_1}\right)$$

Its first derivative cancels at
$$k_0=\frac 1 {x_2-x_1}\,\log \left(\frac{x_2\, y_1}{x_1 \,y_2}\right)$$ as already wriiten by @Griboullis.

To approximate the solution, expand $G(k)$ as a series around $k_0$ to generate
$$k_1=k_0+\sqrt{-2\,\frac{G(k_0) }{G''(k_0) }}$$ For the worked example, this gives $k_1=0.00495774$.

Now, $k_1$ being the starting guess, $\color{red}{\text{one single iteration}}$ of Newton-like method of order $n$ gives an  $\color{red}{\text{explicit formula}}$ for $k_2^{(n)}$.

For the worked example, this gives

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n  & k_2^{(n)} &\text{method} \\
 2 &  0.00530379935784 & \text{Newton} \\
 3 &  0.00528890969515 & \text{Halley} \\
 4 &  0.00529001046153 & \text{Householder} \\
 5 &  0.00528993729050 & \text{no name} \\
 6 &  0.00528994219427 & \text{no name} \\
 7 &  0.00528994186568 & \text{no name} \\
 8 &  0.00528994188770 & \text{no name} \\
\cdots & \cdots  \\
\infty & 0.00528994188633 & \text{solution} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the contribution! So there is a unique solution.

Comment: @wayne. Have a look at the edit ! Funny, isn't it ? By the way, if this is an acceptable answer, may be, you could accept it. Cheers :-)

Comment: So up to rounding the result is unique.

Comment: @wayne. Do not round !

Comment: @wayne While excellent, this answer does not prove that there is always a unique solution.

Comment: @Gribouillis. Did I claim it ? (even if this is true). Cheers :-)

Comment: @Gribouillis It would be interesting to know if there is a unique solution. Under what conditions on $\tau$ and $E_0$ is the solution unique?

Comment: @wayne. I was finishing typing the proof yesterday when my screen teller revealed the big surprise. Then, ........

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Do you agree with the proof of @Gribouillis?

Comment: @JeanMarie. Thanks ! Very interesting. Sorry for missing your call yesterday. Cheers :-)

Comment: Claude, with the same data, I find $k=0.5289941886...$ i.e., exactly a hundred times yours... which, in this very particular case is $-\ln\left(\frac{7+\sqrt{13}}{18}\right)$...

Answer (score 1):

Here is how the number of solutions can be determined. To simplify things, we suppose that
$y_2 \not = y_1$. This implies $E_0\not = 0$ and we can write the equation in the unknown $k = \frac{1}{\tau}\not = 0$
\begin{equation}
g(k):= \frac{y_2}{y_2 - y_1} e^{-k x_1}
 - \frac{y_1}{y_2 - y_1}e^{-k x_2} = 1
\end{equation}
Clearly $g(0)=1$ but $k=0$ is not a valid solution. One has
\begin{equation}
g'(k)= - \frac{x_1 y_2}{y_2 - y_1} e^{-k x_1}
 +  \frac{x_2 y_1}{y_2 - y_1}e^{-k x_2}
\end{equation}
Again we simplify things by assuming that
$x_1 x_2 y_1 y_2 \not = 0$ and $x_1\not = x_2$.

If the quantities $x_1 y_2$ and $x_2 y_1$ have opposite signs, it implies that the sign of
$g'(k)$ is constant, hence $g$ is strictly monotonic. In that case the equation cannot
have a solution $k\not = 0$.

When $x_1 y_2$ and $x_2 y_1$ have the same signs, we have $g'(k_0) = 0$ where
\begin{equation}
k_0 = \frac{1}{x_2-x_1}\log \frac{x_2 y_1}{x_1 y_2}
\end{equation}
It is now easy to see that the equation $g(k) = 1$ can have a valid solution in two cases

- $k_0 > 0$ and $1$ belongs to the interval which bounds are $g(k_0)$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}g(k)$. This solution satisfies $\frac{1}{\tau}\in (k_0,+\infty)$
- $k_0 < 0$ and $1$ belongs to the interval which bounds are $g(k_0)$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to-\infty}g(k)$. This solution satisfies $\frac{1}{\tau}\in (-\infty, k_0)$.

In both cases, the solution is unique.

Comment: A little question of understanding: Why does the opposite sign of the quantities $x_1y_2$ and $x_2y_1$ imply that the sign of $g'(k)$ is constant?

Comment: @wayne because in that case, $g'(k)$ is the sum of two terms having the same sign (the sign of $\frac{x_2 y_1}{y_2 - y_1}$)

Comment: Another question: Why is it important to show that $g'(k_0)=0$?

Comment: @wayne In studying the equation $g(k)=1$ it is extremely useful to study the variations of $g$, that is to say the intervals where $g$ increases and the intervals where it decreases. The frontier points between these intervals are points where $g'(k)=0$ because $g$ is everywhere differentiable. Here we deduce that $g$ is strictly monotonic on both intervals $(-\infty, k_0)$ and $(k_0, +\infty)$.